# How to fetch a webpage with php curl and display that webpage html?

Tags: php, curl

i am new to php and i want to get a webpage html through the use of php curl...i am not getting the output,am just getting a white page.
Can anyone please help?

```
<?php 
$url=$_POST['txturl'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to send URL twice

```
<?php 
$url=$_POST['txturl'];
$ch = curl_init();//I have removed it from here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);// This will do
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

### Check if you really have cURL Installed

```
<?php
echo function_exists('curl_version')?'Yes':'No';
?>
```

Comment: Try this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` , ctrl+F and type 'curl' and see if it is enabled.

Comment: Also add this on top of your PHP code, maybe your error reporting is off. `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: <?php
echo function_exists('curl_version')?'Yes':'No';
?>

i have tried this but neither yes nor No has been displayed